# Runing python3 kivy app build by buildozer on my device give me SDL error

Tags: android, linux, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I have finally managed to build an apk for python 3 and kivy using buildozer, but when I start it on my device I get the following error

[image]

I am using a Linux vm for virtual box on widows to build the apk.
Can you please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Please copy the error to your question with proper [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). If the link of that image ever changes, the value of your question disappears, and it is not the [only reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9269043)

Comment: What python3 recipe did you use?

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).